# laravel 5 Search related models

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, orm

I have two related model.

```
 class Girl extends Model
    {
     public function target()
        {
            //return $this->hasOne('App\Target');
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Target', 'girl_target', 'girl_id',
                'target_id');
        }
    }
```

And

```
class Target extends Model
{
  public function girl()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Girl', 'girl_target');
    }
}
```

How I can find girl model by related target id?

```
  $girls = Girl::where('banned', 0)
             ->with('target');

 $targets=$seachSettings->target()->get();
            if($targets!=null){
                foreach ($targets as $item) {
                    //     $girls->target()->array_where();
                    $girls->target()->where('girl_target','target_id',$item->id);
                }
            }
```

I want get only models where related targets with id from my $targets array.

Comment: u have set wrong relations, which of this belongs, and which is has?, And u need to show your target and girl migrations

Comment: Girll model has many Targets. And if a make      $girl->target()->attach($target); it work.

Comment: `$targets` has several `id`, and if one girl has many targets, and these target only include one of those ids in `$targets`, do u want them, or you need the girl has all those `$targets` ids?

Comment: I want that girl has all those $targets ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `whereHas()` method

```php
$girls = Girl::whereHas('target', function ($query) use($item) {
    $query->where('id', $item->id);
})->where('banned', 0)->with('target');
```

Answer (score 0):

define the relationship between `Girl` and `Target`

```
class Girl extends Model
    {
     public function target(): HasMany
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Target', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
        }
    }

class Target extends Model
{
  public function girl(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Girl', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
    }
}
```

and then if u want to get girl targets, just call

```
$targets = Girl::find(1)->target;
```

or if u want to get girl by target

```
$girl = Target::find(1)->girl;
```